# Let $G = GL(2,F)$ and $B$ be the subgroup of upper triangular matrices in $G$. Show $ B \backslash G/B = \{ B,BwB \} $

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Complete question:

> Let $G = GL(2,F)$ and $B$ be the subgroup of upper triangular matrices in $G$. 
>   Show that $ B \backslash G/B = \{ B,BwB \}$ where $w \in GL(2,F) $ is the matrix $
>   \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
>    0 & -1 \\
>    1 & 0 \\
>   \end{array} } \right) $

***Notation:**

> $ H \backslash G/K = \{\, HgK \mid g \in G\}$ denotes the set of all double cosets. Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $G$ as: for $ x,y \in G, \, x \sim y \iff \exists \, h\in H,k\in K$ such that $x=hyk $. From which it can be seen that equivalence classes of $a\in G$ are $HaK$ and  $G=\bigcup\limits_{x\in G} HxK$

**My attempt :**  Clearly $\{B,BwB\} \subseteq B\backslash G/B.$ Now $\forall a_i,b_i,c_i \in F ,\,\, A,A' \in B$ and $M \in G$ consider,

$$ AMA' = \left( {\begin{array}{cc}  a_1 & b_1 \\ 0 & c_1 \\  \end{array} } \right) 
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}  a & b \\ c & d \\  \end{array} } \right) 
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}  a_2 & b_2 \\ 0 & c_2 \\  \end{array} } \right)
$$ 
$$ = \left( {\begin{array}{cc}  a(a_2a_1)+c(a_2b_1) & a(b_2a_1)+b(c_2a_1)+c(b_1b_2)+d(c_1c_2) \\ c(c_1a_2) & c(b_2c_1)+d(c_2c_1) \\  \end{array} } \right) 
$$

if $c=0$ then this implies $AMA' \in B$. If $c\neq 0 $, then i have to show $AMA' \in BwB$.

Now I am not able to further progress in the proof. Is there any other better way to solve this problem?

Comment: $B$ is the stabilizer of a $1$-dimensional subspace of the $2$-dimensional vestor space $V$ on which $G$ acts naturally, so this assertion  is equivalent to the fact that $G$ acts 2-transitively on the set of $1$-dimensional subspaces of $V$.

Answer (score 1):

If $c \neq 0$, you need to find two upper triangular matrices $M_1, M_2$ such that $M_1 \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}M_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Try to think in terms of row and column operations. The first reduction to try is to apply two shearing operations, i.e., find $b_1, b_2$ such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & b_1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & b_2 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & b' \\ c & 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

This is possible since $c \neq 0$. Then, another scaling matrix either in the front or in the back suffices.